# How to add Google Chart into Orkut Scrapbook?

Tags: orkut, google-chart-api

I want to add [Google Charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) into [Orkut](http://www.orkut.com/) [Scrapbook](http://www.orkut.co.in/Main#Scrapbook). How can I do that without hosting the Image?

Comment: See [this question](http://chat.webapps.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/569#569) on [Google Chatroom](http://chat.webapps.stackexchange.com/rooms/5/google)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you do not need to host the actual image of the chart. On the contrary, you provide the chart parameters as a URL, it get created and hosted by Google, and you get shown the result.

So all you have to do is add an image and set it's source to create the desired chart.

Case in point:

```
https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=200x125&chbh=15,10&chd=s:ATSTaVd21981uocA&chco=224499&chm=h,76A4FB,0,0:1:.2,.5,-1|V,76A4FB,0,::2,.5,-1|v,ff0000,0,::.75,3,-1
```

yields

[image]

and

```
https://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=bvs&chs=150x100&chbh=15,10&chd=t2:10,20,30,20,70,80|20,10,5,20,30,10|10,0,20,15,60,40,30&chds=0,120&chco=224499,009900&chm=D,76A4FB,2,0,3|N,FF0000,-1,-1,10
```

yields

[image]

**PS based on recommendation in comments**: Shortening the URL is a great idea. i.e., the last chart can be embedded as `tinyurl.com/y7fqgyd` - tried it and it works

[image]

Comment: But I want to add the chart in Orkut Scrapbook. This link is not works fpr Orkut. How can I do that?

Comment: did you try wrapping those links trough URL shortners?

Comment: Shortening the URL is a great idea. i.e., the last chart can be embedded as http://tinyurl.com/y7fqgyd - tried it and it works

Comment: @alexanderpas Great. But Add the "URL Shorting" idea with the answer (+10 reps) so that, it will be easily available to others... Thanks...

Comment: Added URL shortening to answer - thanks for the suggestion